# Is it cd an option to access a windows directory from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I have a dual boot Linux/windows, i would like to know if it is possible to access a windows directory from within Linux using the cd command

Comment: If the NTFS filesystem is mounted first, then "yes".  Yours is probably a duplicate question.

Comment: You may also be interested that the reverse is also true: you can access an ext2/3/4 file system from Windows using the open source [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/).

Comment: If you specify the Linux Distribution you should have a more precise answers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You first need to [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) the Windows file system. Most desktop-oriented distros will do this for you automatically, at a path like `/mount/windows` or something. It's possible even if not, though; you need root permissions and you need to know which block device (disk) holds your Windows partition, but that's usually easy enough to discover.

Once the Windows partition is mounted in your Linux file system layout, you can easily `cd` to it, just as you could to any other directory. Basically, the Windows partition appears as subdirectories of the Linux directory (called a *mount point*) that you choose.

An example that creates a Windows directory at the root of your Linux partition, and mounts the first partition of the first disk (this is often where Windows will be, though it might be on the second partition instead) there:

```
# mkdir /Windows
# mount /dev/sda1 /Windows
```

Note that you can, if you want, do things like mount the Windows volume read-only (add the `-r` flag before the `/dev/sda1` part) or use an existing (but *must be empty*) directory. Note also that Linux will not, generally speaking, respect the NTFS access controls. This means that you might accidentally delete or modify something important on the Windows system.

If you want the OS to remember your mount point, and optionally also to automatically mount the partition, take a look at the [/etc/fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) file. Unfortunately, there's no standard way to edit this file that I know of, though its format isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can use `cd` to change directory on a windows file system, **if it is  mounted somewhere in your filesystem**, and if you have the right to enter in that directory... else you have to mount it.

1. Search **if it is just mounted**, you should find the windows partition under `/mnt/windows`, `/media/Data`, `/media/Windows` and so on; write form a terminal `mount` and search for the keywords **ntfs-3g, ntfs, fuseblk**. It is just mounted if it will answer something like

   > /dev/sda2 on **/media/Windows** type **fuseblk** (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

   In this case **`/media/Windows` is the mounting point**, the equivalent of `C:\` or `D:\` under windows. To access it write

   > cd **/media/Windows**

   Note: you can argue the mounting point with the `fd -h` command too; it will report the file system disk space usage (on all the partition currently mounted); in the last column you can see the mounting point.
2. If it is not mounted you have to mount it, t**hen change directory to the mounting point as above**. To mount the windows partition follow your distribution guide and/or read some of those references:

   - [Ubuntu Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)
   - [How to mount partition with ntfs file system and read write access](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access), use **ntfs-3g**.
   - [Mounting NTFS Drives on Linux](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux)
   - [Mount NTFS Windows partition on Ubuntu live CD](https://superuser.com/a/352199/257269)
   - or edit directly the `/etc/fstab` file adding lines as

> UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F /media/Win ntfs-3g defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
>   UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F /media/ReadOnlyWin  ntfs  defaults,umask=222  0 0

Replace the UUID with the one relevant for your partition as shown in the `sudo blkid`  output. “519CB82E5888AD0F” will not work for you. The 1st line adds with the read and write permission the windows partition under `/media/Win`, the 2nd line adds the same partition with only read permission under `/media/ReadOnlyWin`. You do not need to write both.

Notes:

- In many distributions the original `ntfs`, is linked to `ntfs-3g`: in the beginning with `ntfs` Linux was capable to mount NTFS file system *"read only"*, so in some distributions if you use *ntfs* in your *fstab* it will attempt to use that kernel driver, and mount your NTFS as read only.
- A traditional mount point is under `/mnt/windows` but each directory can be good.
  You can mount more than one time (in 2 different places) one with the option *readonly* and one with the possibility to write in... and you can decide to mount the writeable one only when needed.
- Help of ArchLinux [*ntfs-g3 here*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G)